# How to make a Minecraft server stop daily at a specific time (1 am)

Tags: minecraft

I am running a small Minecraft server for me and a few friends.

I already managed to make the server start when I login using

```
cd paperserver/
./start.sh
```

in `bashrc` And when the server is running the terminal looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYb8a.jpg).
If I want to stop the server I simply need to type `stop` in the terminal.

Now I am trying to make the server stop and make the pc shut off daily at 1 am. I have been looking around for a way to do this but since I am very new to using ubuntu I am having a hard time understanding guides I find online.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images (or links to images) of text. Instead, copy/paste the text directly into your question.

Comment: Either this is baked into Minecraft, in which case the Minecraft support community is where I'd look for suggestions, or you need to script it. 

Otherwise you are looking for a command to shut down the server safely -- once you have that you can run it at 1AM with `cron`. My guess is that the [Unix/Linux stack exchange community][1] will  be better able to help you figure out whether or not that is possible. 


  [1]: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with crontab:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `sudo crontab -e`
3. Enter the following:

```
0 1 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

This will shut the machine down at 1:00am every day come heck or high water.

Comment: Thank you, but before the pc shuts off I also want the server to stop so everything gets saved. Is there a way to do this automatically? Or does using your method also save the server?